# How can I count the number of events in the google calendar API in node js?

Tags: node.js, function, events, google-calendar-api

I'm using dialogflow to build and chatbot and I'm integrating it with Google Calendar. I've already been able to book an appointment but my problem is that i would like to count the number of events present in a time interval. I can do this using the following code that writes me the right value in the log:

```
  function get_events(dateTimeStart1,dateTimeEnd1){
    calendar.events.list({  // List all events in the specified time period
      auth: serviceAccountAuth,
      calendarId: calendarId,
      timeMin: dateTimeStart1.toISOString(),
      timeMax: dateTimeEnd1.toISOString()
    }, (err,res) => {
    const events = res.data.items;
      const number_events = events.length;
      console.log(number_events);
    });
  }
```

The problem is that i would like to **return** the value **number_events** to use it for other purposes but i don't know how to do it.

I would like to do something like this.

```
  function get_events(dateTimeStart1,dateTimeEnd1){
    calendar.events.list({  // List all events in the specified time period
      auth: serviceAccountAuth,
      calendarId: calendarId,
      timeMin: dateTimeStart1.toISOString(),
      timeMax: dateTimeEnd1.toISOString()
    }, (err,res) => {
    const events = res.data.items;
      const number_events = events.length;
      console.log(number_events);
    });
  return number_events;
  }
```

Can you please help me? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

How about this answer? `calendar.events.list` returns the Promise. So you can modify as follows.

#### Modified script:

In this modification, it supposes that `get_events` is called in the function `run`.

```
async function get_events(dateTimeStart1,dateTimeEnd1){
  const res = await calendar.events.list({
    auth: serviceAccountAuth,
    calendarId: calendarId,
    timeMin: dateTimeStart1.toISOString(),
    timeMax: dateTimeEnd1.toISOString(),
  });
  const events = res.data.items;
  const number_events = events.length;
  return number_events;
}

async function run() {

  // do something

  const res = await get_events(dateTimeStart1, dateTimeEnd1);
  console.log(res);

  // do something

}
```

#### Reference:

- [googleapis for Node.js](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/)

### Added:

Although I'm not sure whether this is the direction you expect, when `async functions` is not used, how about the following script?

```
function get_events(dateTimeStart1, dateTimeEnd1) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    calendar.events.list(
      {
        auth: serviceAccountAuth,
        calendarId: calendarId,
        timeMin: dateTimeStart1.toISOString(),
        timeMax: dateTimeEnd1.toISOString(),
      },
      (err, res) => {
        if (err) reject(err);
        const events = res.data.items;
        const number_events = events.length;
        resolve(number_events);
      }
    );
  });
}

function run(creds) {
  // do something

  get_events(calendar, dateTimeStart1, dateTimeEnd1).then((res) =>
    console.log(res)
  );

  // do something
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I'm using Dialogflow and it reports the error: "async functions' is only available in es8 (use 'esversion 8')". Is there a way I can do the same wthout an async function?

Comment: @Luca Di Narzo Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize again.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually the function you posted writes the right value to the log but doens't let me use this variable "number_events". It's returned to me an [Object Promise]. My goal is to use the "number_events" as condition for a while loop. In particular I want to set: while (number_events > 0) do something.

Comment: @Luca Di Narzo Thank you for replying. From your question, I couldn't notice that you wanted to use `calendar.events.list` in a loop. I apologize for my poor English skill. When you want to use `calendar.events.list` in a loop, in that case, `async functions` is required to be used. How about this?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Using the async function is not possible in dialogflow as it returns an error so i can't use it.

Comment: @Luca Di Narzo Thank you for replying. In that case, in order to wait for finishing `calendar.events.list`, for example, how about using the sleep? But I don't think that this is better and I'm not sure whether this is the direction you expect. So if this was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Comment: Hi Tanaike, can you explain how you’d use the sleep? Thank you

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. When `async function` cannot be used, how about waiting for finishing `calendar.events.list` using the sleep for several seconds?